# discord.js - bot get kicked out of voice channel event

Tags: discord.js, disconnect

What I tried to do for my music bot was getting him to report when he gets kicked out of a voice channel, by saying for example "I was forcefully disconnected". I didnt find a useful property or method to check this, so I asked for help to some friends and tried this:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
      let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel

      if (newUserChannel === undefined) return console.log("I was kicked from the voice channel")
    })
```

It didnt work.

So, is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same proble some time ago.
This is the way i used to solve it:

```js
Client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  
  // Represents a mute/deafen update
  if(oldState.channelId === newState.chanelId) return console.log('Mute/Deafen Update');

  // Some connection
  if(!oldState.channelId && newState.channelId) return console.log('Connection Update');

  // Disconnection
  if(oldState.channelId && !newState.channelId){
    console.log('Disconnection Update');
    // Bot was disconnected?
    if(newState.id === Client.user.id) return console.log(`${Client.user.username} was disconnected!`);
  }
});
```

Since the **voiceStateUpdate** event is fired in everything related to voice channels, you should add as much scenarios as possible to make things work as intended.

Comment: sorry but this doesnt work, it doesnt give me any responses or errors, only the mute deaf works but I currently dont need it

Comment: Do you have GUILD_VOICE_STATES intent?